# I want to delete all files which are in a folder in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I made a child in Firebase Storage. the child has a user's image, and tweet image or something.
when the user wants to delete his account, I have to delete all the information of the user.
so, I want to delete the storage child at once. but it didn't work.
how can I delete the child like a folder that has all the files of the user??

Comment: "*but it didn't work*" - what didn't work?  Always show the code that isn't working the way you expect, so we can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place the delete function when the user clicks on delete account button.

```
desertRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // File deleted successfully
    }}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
    }
});
```

For more information, you should see this [article](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/automatically-delete-your-firebase-storage-files-from-firestore-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-36542c39ba0d) and this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/delete-files).